# Selenium driver.findElement finds element, sendKeys works, then nulls out when moving to a new field

Tags: java, selenium, sendkeys

Using Selenium I am successfully finding element and adding info using sendKeys.  However, when it moves to the next driver.findElement field it nulls out the previous field.  I have many fields that I am searching for and filling out but not understanding why it is nulling out the fields when it moves on.

Code example (finds field, types "MO" but nulls it out when moving to the Office question).  It then fills the Office information but nulls it out when moving to the next field:

```
//User's Associated Region question
driver.findElement(By.id("QS005056A70C8EB9m8UADBe4DAdW0C_input")).sendKeys("MO");
System.out.println("Set User's Associated Region");

//User's Associated Office question
driver.findElement(By.id("QS005056A70C8E4dm8UAFmq7DAm38C_input")).sendKeys("1234 KANSAS CITY COMPLEX");
System.out.println("Set User's Associated Office");
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try the actions manually, does the same problem occur?
Does the id of the element change after using sendKeys?

Comment: When I try the actions manually the fields set correctly and are not nulled out.  The element id stays the same after using sendKeys.  It is when it moves to the next element and does the sendKeys on that one that the first one is nulled.  These fields build off of each other when you set it manually. ( EX:  2nd can't be set till first is set, 3rd can't be set till 2nd is set, etc.)

Comment: What is the result if you do ``getAttribute("value")`` or ``getText()``

``String elementValueOne = driver.findElement(By.id("QS005056A70C8EWNe8UAZYOxDAVk0C")).getAttribute("value"); 
String elementValueTwo = driver.findElement(By.id("QS005056A70C8EWNe8UAZYOxDAVk0C")).getText();``

Comment: I tried getAttribute and it does nothing.  No errors, but it doesn't set the field.

Comment: Could you try to use getAttribute and getText after you set it with sendKeys?

Comment: I tried getAttribute and getText and it did the same thing.

Comment: @Terri Does the field also null out when filling in manually?